Html helpers causing errors in ASP.NET MVC
<tr>
    <td>@Html.LabelFor(LoginVM => model.UserName)</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName)</td>
    <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Password)</td>
    <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)</td>
</tr>

I get this error:

Error (active) CS0012
The type 'Expression<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.  1_Views_PrismLogin_Index.cshtml C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\PrismReplica\Views\PrismLogin\Index.cshtml  23

I tried to add reference manually upon which it says already added by the build.
System.Core version 4.0.0.0 is unchecked and I'm unable to check it
I updated all the packages, cleaned and rebuilt the solution.

Did you try and restart Visual Studio? That sometimes helps with these strange errors

OT - "C:\Users\Administrator" Why are you programming using an administrator account?

From my own experience of this error I found this link, hopefully a help for you.
The type 'Expression<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced
The part that worked for me was adding:
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />

to my web.config in System.Web.
